# ItemDataBound and ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to set an ItemDataBound event for a nested Repeater.

I write this code for ItemDataBound EventHandler.

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
 Tour dataitem = (Tour)(e.Item.DataItem);
 ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1 = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");

 ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["Id"].DefaultValue =  dataitem.TourId.ToString();
}
```

it seems this line works correctly

```
Tour dataitem = (Tour)(e.Item.DataItem);
```

and my problem starts here:
I have this exception

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

for line

```
ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["Id"].DefaultValue =  dataitem.TourId.ToString();
```

but the problem is in this line

```
        ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1 = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
```

I need to know why This line is needed.

if I omit this one it dosent work properly yet but there is no error. 
as it knows my objectdatasource control why its needed ?

I need some explanation about this line and how to fix the exception . i didnt use try catch yet.

I follow this article to code this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510144.aspx

Comment: Is the _"ObjectDataSource1"_ nested inside your nested repeater or is it outside? Can you post your front-end repeater and _"ObjectDataSource1"_ code

Comment: @zgood yesssssssss it was the exact problem.I didnt put the objectdatasource nested. now I put it Nested and it works correctly. is it possible to answer this question then I can Accept it and vote for you . really thank you.

Comment: Ok I will post an answer to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access *"ObjectDataSource1"* from the ItemDataBound event of the nested Repeater the ObjectDataSource would need be nested inside this Repeater.

The reason `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` was because the *"ObjectDataSource1"* was not found inside this Repeater when `(ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1")` was called.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tour dataitem = (Tour)(e.Item.DataItem);
```

The above line should be

```
Tour dataitem = (Tour)(((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)).Row;
```

Also you need to check whether dataitem is null

```
if(dataitem != null)
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["Id"].DefaultValue =  dataitem.TourId.ToString();
```

And you need this line to obtain a reference to your objectdatasource used in the front end code bound to the repeater, so that you can set the TourId of the Tour object.

```
ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1 = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
```